# Running a Python script saved on a Windows 7 server... on a Mac?

Tags: python, macos, windows-7

We have a server running Windows 7 Pro. I have several Python script I'd like to save to the server and have it so that client computers can run them by simply double-clicking. The client computers are all running OSX. This is proving to be... problematic.

First I tried to simply make the Python scripts executable, but this doesn't seem to be possible on a Windows server -- since you can't set the 'executable' flag, double-clicking on a file will always open it in an editor (unless I were to go to every single computer and make .py files open with Python). Trying to create a shell script has the same problem -- there's no way to make them executable from the server.

My solution was to just make a simple AppleScript app that sends a command to launch the script. Unfortunately, as soon as I copy the app to the server, it stops working. It seems that OSX apps refuse to execute properly when saved to the server -- if you run the file, nothing happens at all.

Is there a simple solution I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you're looking for: http://oreilly.com/catalog/samba/chapter/book/ch05_03.html says that Samba clients (that OS X uses to connect to Windows shares) can map archive/hidden/system file attributes to owner/group/world executable bits respectively.

Try setting those attributes on the script file and make sure its first line is `#!/usr/bin/python`. If this mapping is enabled by default, the script will run by double-click.

Comment: I'm guessing if the Windows server is using some proprietary system to facilitate mounting, and the system doesn't support permission mapping, I'm out of luck?

Comment: If OS X clients connect via smb://, it's only matter of their SMB client configuration.

Comment: They don't :(  Drives are mounted via proprietary software on each of the client computers.

Comment: Maybe creating an application bundle will work. AFAIK the file in /Contents/MacOS does not have to be executable, however I can't check right now whether it can be a script.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it needs to be executable. If I copy a simple application made with the AppleScript Editor to the server, the 'applet' file in /Contents/MacOS/ loses its execute bit and the program refuses to run.

Answer (score 0):

actually the issue is that windows has no equivalent of the *execute bit* for files.

the solution is to change the mount options on the share so that all the files have their execute bit set.